# jQuery Notification plugin compatible with IE 7

Tags: jquery

It is a very tedious job to test every jQuery notification plugins out there.

Has anyone knows any jQuery notification plugin that is compatible with at least Internet Explorer 7?

Comment: better to author it.....:)

Comment: @Jai Thanks, but yeah, I do it when I'm not in a fast-pacing deadline, hehe.

Comment: Oh I found one, compatible from IE7: http://justindomingue.github.io/ohSnap/ . If anyone knows better one, I'll gladly appreciate.